# Using facebook sdk php without json + jsonwrapper doesn't work?

Tags: php, json, facebook

I am still on php 5.1.x and JSON isnt available. Now in the past i used jsonwrapper but with facebook php sdk, it doesn't seem to work

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Facebook needs the JSON PHP extension.'

Is there another workaround??

Comment: I have not looked at the Facebook API in a long time, but could you not just modify the API to use jsonwrapper calls?  (I am presuming that the API is throwing the exception)

Comment: a quick google search also directed me here if this helps:
http://www.epigroove.com/posts/97/how_to_use_json_in_php_4_or_php_51x

Comment: if FB API checks explicity if json extension is loaded tehn that workaround can't work

Comment: @yes123 *unless* you modify the api to disregard the check and modify the API to use jsonwrapper calls instead of json calls.  As I recall the API is really not that big (unless things have changed in the last couple years)

Comment: @Aaron, tx tried your link and it didn't work. A closer look and it was the same class i already tried to use with the jsonwrapper.

Comment: @yes123, i hear you and @Aaron i have just downloaded FB 3, i will check for FB 2 maybe that will still work with jsonwrapper

Comment: OH NO! OH NO! stupid me

uh........i was wrongly including the stuff.

include('../src/facebook.php');
include('jsonwrapper.php');

change it to

include('jsonwrapper.php');
include('../src/facebook.php');

Comment: @alex good stuff, that would do it! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a solution without install o modify nothing (spanish)

http://cimientosprevios.com/?p=39

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You shouldn't just give a link to another site as an answer, since the site may go out of date in the future. Instead, click the "edit" link on this answer and include the essential parts of the solution from that page here. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259